# How to check is my application using Tor?

Tags: torsocks

I write a linux application for exchanging voice messages over Tor (via TCP). I would start my program like this:

```
torsocks my_program --connect abcdabcdabcdabcd5.onion
```

Is there some way my program (written in C) can check that environment is torifyed? I wish my program print warning message when it try to resolve .onion domain without torsocks.

I have tried this code:

```
if (!getenv("LD_PRELOAD")) printf("LD_PRELOAD is %s\n", getenv("LD_PRELOAD"));
else printf("LD_PRELOAD is not set\n");
```

On the torifyed shell it returns "LD_PRELOAD is not set", and in normal shell it returns "LD_PRELOAD is (null)"

(Sorry my bad english)